# Gradle failed to download com.google.android.gms play-services-ads/15.0.0/play-services-ads.pom

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, admob, build.gradle

i am trying to add admob banner ads to an android app..But when i put 
"implementation'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'" in dependencies the gradle failed to download it ..
Anny help

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all 
  sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
  }

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
   }
 }

 task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

Comment: You should really add some info, there can be various reasons.

Comment: You can also try this  :~ implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1' its also might use '11.8.0'

Comment: I tried 
:~ implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1' and  '11.8.0' not working .. istill cannt download it !! ..@HarshitTrivedi 
@sr9yar

Answer (score 0):

Use `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'` and not 15.0.0

Also share some more detail so we can provide more accurate answer